# Forcing execution plan with local join hints

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, execution-plan

I have several encounters with bad execution plans in batch jobs during a week, and to avoid forcing plans I have moved on to adding local join hints (when these join types are the difference between good and bad execution plans). This way I get SQL Server to choose most of the plan, while enforcing the few joins I know are necessary to be able to finish the queries.

In the execution plans below, I want to enforce the join types to be somewhat the same and will therefore use local joins hints also for these. However, I was wondering if I am able to trigger other actions in the execution plans as well, such as:

List item

- SORT(Distinct Sort)
- Stram Aggregate(Aggregate)

Are these actions something I can choose, or are they dependent on join types/order choosed during the query?

Both plans are created by XML extracted from Query Store.

Good execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyYMn7K2V

Bad execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hka6i7Yh4

Comment: Hi, Query was slightly changed in february and execution time went from hours to seconds. It has degraded again without being changed. Project has ended and there is no funding to do the complete testing needed for a new rewriting of these steps in the jobs, hence that is not an alternative. I believe these issues are caused by skewed statistics due to failed maintenance job (full transaction LOG). This join should always be a hash join (300m+ rows compared with 300m+ rows). Ever increasing tables. I guess this is the main issue, but then again, I cannot change behaviour but need it to finish.

Comment: When looking at the statistics information in the query plan, the only difference is on the statistics on the `cte_MDTForsikringssum` table being 100% on the 'good plan' and 42,..% on the 'bad plan'  `SamplingPercent="42.3373` vs. `SamplingPercent="100"` Next to that, the compiled parameters are different: E.G for `@kjorenr = 89025` for the 'good plan' and `@kjorenr =  89110` for the 'bad plan' The date timeframe is also ~3 days for the bad plan's compiled parameters while the good plan only has a timeframe of ~1 day. (`@SluttDato` & `@StartDato`)

Comment: I agree with Randi. Id start by updating stats and maybe rebuilding indexes. If yr using sql 2016+ query store might be useful in helping diagnose this. Altering indexes or maybe even dropping indexes may help. Id consider changing stats and indexes before altering a query.

Answer (score 7):

> I want to enforce the join types to be somewhat the same and will
>   therefore use local joins hints also for these

Adding join hints should be a last resort. There should be ways to rewrite the query / add indexes to get a more consistent result.

These plans are also estimated execution plans, in this case only you knows how well / bad the actual query will perform.

If the issue is parameter sniffing, `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` would be the easiest solution.

Is the `LEFT JOIN` only used for filtering? A `NOT EXISTS` might work better to filter earlier.

Having said all that, with the limited information given, here are some possible, quick rewrites.

**Rewrite #1 `LEFT JOIN` to `NOT EXISTS`**

The `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`is added to get better estimates based on the parameters provided.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.cte_MDTForsikringssum
 SELECT DISTINCT
   mdtp.AvtaleNummer
  ,mdtp.MedlemskapNummer
  ,mdtp.Dekningstype
  ,mdtp.StartAlder
  ,mdtp.OpphorsAlder
  ,mdtp.PeriodeStartDato AS GjelderFraDato
  ,NULL GjelderTilDato
  ,mdtp.AjourholdDato AS EndretDato
  ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,8), 0) AS Forsikringssum
  ,0 AS Avkortningsfaktor
  ,0 AS PensjonsgivendeGrunnlag
  ,0 AS Folketrygd
  ,mdtp.Kjorenr_k
 FROM [BMPERSIST].vips.impMedlemskapDekningTrinnPremie_full mdtp

 INNER JOIN
  (SELECT
   AvtaleNummer,
   MedlemskapNummer,
   Dekningstype,
   StartAlder,
   OpphorsAlder,
   YEAR(PeriodeStartDato) AS PeriodeStartDatoAar,
   MONTH(PeriodeStartDato) AS PeriodeStartDatoManed,
   MAX(AjourholdDato) AS maxAjourholdDato
  FROM [BMPERSIST].vips.impMedlemskapDekningTrinnPremie_full 
  WHERE --PeriodeStartDato < @dato--GETDATE()
   ( -- 27.03.2019 Endret WHERE betingelser lik neste step for å minske datamengden i TEMP tabell
    (PeriodeStartDato BETWEEN @StartDato AND @SluttDato) 
    OR (Kjorenr_k = @kjorenr AND PeriodeStartDato < @dato)
   )
  AND KVID_Kontotype IN (189 --ArligInnskudd
        ,412,413 --AdmRes
        ,190,407,408,409,410,411,591) --Risiko
  GROUP BY
   AvtaleNummer,
   MedlemskapNummer,
   Dekningstype,
   StartAlder,
   OpphorsAlder,
   YEAR(PeriodeStartDato),
   MONTH(PeriodeStartDato)
  ) ajourholdD
 ON ajourholdD.AvtaleNummer = mdtp.AvtaleNummer
 AND ajourholdD.MedlemskapNummer = mdtp.MedlemskapNummer
 AND ajourholdD.Dekningstype = mdtp.Dekningstype
 AND ajourholdD.StartAlder = mdtp.StartAlder
 AND ajourholdD.OpphorsAlder = mdtp.OpphorsAlder
 AND ajourholdD.PeriodeStartDatoAar = YEAR(mdtp.PeriodeStartDato)
 AND ajourholdD.PeriodeStartDatoManed = MONTH(mdtp.PeriodeStartDato)
 AND ajourholdD.maxAjourholdDato = mdtp.AjourholdDato
 WHERE mdtp.PeriodeStartDato <= @dato
 AND NOT EXISTS
 (
 SELECT * FROM
 dbo.cte_MDTForsikringssum dest
 WHERE dest.AvtaleNummer = mdtp.AvtaleNummer
 AND dest.MedlemskapNummer = mdtp.MedlemskapNummer
 AND dest.Dekningstype = mdtp.Dekningstype
 AND dest.StartAlder = mdtp.StartAlder
 AND dest.OpphorsAlder = mdtp.OpphorsAlder
 AND dest.GjelderFraDato = mdtp.PeriodeStartDato
 AND dest.EndretDato = mdtp.AjourholdDato
 )
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

**Rewrite #2 Also removing the `OR` by using `UNION`**

```
   INSERT INTO dbo.cte_MDTForsikringssum
 SELECT DISTINCT
   mdtp.AvtaleNummer
  ,mdtp.MedlemskapNummer
  ,mdtp.Dekningstype
  ,mdtp.StartAlder
  ,mdtp.OpphorsAlder
  ,mdtp.PeriodeStartDato AS GjelderFraDato
  ,NULL GjelderTilDato
  ,mdtp.AjourholdDato AS EndretDato
  ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,8), 0) AS Forsikringssum
  ,0 AS Avkortningsfaktor
  ,0 AS PensjonsgivendeGrunnlag
  ,0 AS Folketrygd
  ,mdtp.Kjorenr_k
 FROM [BMPERSIST].vips.impMedlemskapDekningTrinnPremie_full mdtp
 INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
    AvtaleNummer,
    MedlemskapNummer,
    Dekningstype,
    StartAlder,
    OpphorsAlder,
    YEAR(PeriodeStartDato) AS PeriodeStartDatoAar,
    MONTH(PeriodeStartDato) AS PeriodeStartDatoManed,
    MAX(AjourholdDato) AS maxAjourholdDato
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT
    AvtaleNummer,
    MedlemskapNummer,
    Dekningstype,
    StartAlder,
    OpphorsAlder,
    PeriodeStartDato,
    AjourholdDato
    FROM
    [BMPERSIST].vips.impMedlemskapDekningTrinnPremie_full 
    WHERE --PeriodeStartDato < @dato--GETDATE()
    ( -- 27.03.2019 Endret WHERE betingelser lik neste step for å minske datamengden i TEMP tabell
    (PeriodeStartDato BETWEEN @StartDato AND @SluttDato) 
    )
    AND KVID_Kontotype IN (189 --ArligInnskudd
        ,412,413 --AdmRes
        ,190,407,408,409,410,411,591) --Risiko      
    UNION
    SELECT
    AvtaleNummer,
    MedlemskapNummer,
    Dekningstype,
    StartAlder,
    OpphorsAlder,
    PeriodeStartDato,
    AjourholdDato
    FROM [BMPERSIST].vips.impMedlemskapDekningTrinnPremie_full 
    WHERE
    (Kjorenr_k = @kjorenr AND PeriodeStartDato < @dato)
    AND KVID_Kontotype IN (189 --ArligInnskudd
        ,412,413 --AdmRes
        ,190,407,408,409,410,411,591) --Risiko
  ) AS A
GROUP BY
AvtaleNummer,
MedlemskapNummer,
Dekningstype,
StartAlder,
OpphorsAlder,
YEAR(PeriodeStartDato),
MONTH(PeriodeStartDato)
 ) 
  ajourholdD
 ON ajourholdD.AvtaleNummer = mdtp.AvtaleNummer
 AND ajourholdD.MedlemskapNummer = mdtp.MedlemskapNummer
 AND ajourholdD.Dekningstype = mdtp.Dekningstype
 AND ajourholdD.StartAlder = mdtp.StartAlder
 AND ajourholdD.OpphorsAlder = mdtp.OpphorsAlder
 AND ajourholdD.PeriodeStartDatoAar = YEAR(mdtp.PeriodeStartDato)
 AND ajourholdD.PeriodeStartDatoManed = MONTH(mdtp.PeriodeStartDato)
 AND ajourholdD.maxAjourholdDato = mdtp.AjourholdDato
 WHERE mdtp.PeriodeStartDato <= @dato
 AND NOT EXISTS
 (
 SELECT * FROM
 dbo.cte_MDTForsikringssum dest
 WHERE dest.AvtaleNummer = mdtp.AvtaleNummer
 AND dest.MedlemskapNummer = mdtp.MedlemskapNummer
 AND dest.Dekningstype = mdtp.Dekningstype
 AND dest.StartAlder = mdtp.StartAlder
 AND dest.OpphorsAlder = mdtp.OpphorsAlder
 AND dest.GjelderFraDato = mdtp.PeriodeStartDato
 AND dest.EndretDato = mdtp.AjourholdDato
 )
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

**Rewrite #3 Adding an additional temp table to store the inner join**

By adding a temp table to split up the queries, the optimizer might get better estimates on the final query.

```
 SELECT
   AvtaleNummer,
   MedlemskapNummer,
   Dekningstype,
   StartAlder,
   OpphorsAlder,
   YEAR(PeriodeStartDato) AS PeriodeStartDatoAar,
   MONTH(PeriodeStartDato) AS PeriodeStartDatoManed,
   MAX(AjourholdDato) AS maxAjourholdDato
INTO #TEMP
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT
    AvtaleNummer,
    MedlemskapNummer,
    Dekningstype,
    StartAlder,
    OpphorsAlder,
    PeriodeStartDato,
    AjourholdDato
    FROM
    [BMPERSIST].vips.impMedlemskapDekningTrinnPremie_full 
    WHERE --PeriodeStartDato < @dato--GETDATE()
    ( -- 27.03.2019 Endret WHERE betingelser lik neste step for å minske datamengden i TEMP tabell
    (PeriodeStartDato BETWEEN @StartDato AND @SluttDato) 
    )
    AND KVID_Kontotype IN (189 --ArligInnskudd
        ,412,413 --AdmRes
        ,190,407,408,409,410,411,591) --Risiko      
    UNION
    SELECT
    AvtaleNummer,
    MedlemskapNummer,
    Dekningstype,
    StartAlder,
    OpphorsAlder,
    PeriodeStartDato,
    AjourholdDato
    FROM [BMPERSIST].vips.impMedlemskapDekningTrinnPremie_full 
    WHERE
    (Kjorenr_k = @kjorenr AND PeriodeStartDato < @dato)
    AND KVID_Kontotype IN (189 --ArligInnskudd
        ,412,413 --AdmRes
        ,190,407,408,409,410,411,591) --Risiko
  ) AS A

INSERT INTO dbo.cte_MDTForsikringssum
 SELECT DISTINCT
   mdtp.AvtaleNummer
  ,mdtp.MedlemskapNummer
  ,mdtp.Dekningstype
  ,mdtp.StartAlder
  ,mdtp.OpphorsAlder
  ,mdtp.PeriodeStartDato AS GjelderFraDato
  ,NULL GjelderTilDato
  ,mdtp.AjourholdDato AS EndretDato
  ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,8), 0) AS Forsikringssum
  ,0 AS Avkortningsfaktor
  ,0 AS PensjonsgivendeGrunnlag
  ,0 AS Folketrygd
  ,mdtp.Kjorenr_k
 FROM [BMPERSIST].vips.impMedlemskapDekningTrinnPremie_full mdtp

 INNER JOIN
  (
  SELECT * 
  FROM #TEMP
  ) ajourholdD
 ON ajourholdD.AvtaleNummer = mdtp.AvtaleNummer
 AND ajourholdD.MedlemskapNummer = mdtp.MedlemskapNummer
 AND ajourholdD.Dekningstype = mdtp.Dekningstype
 AND ajourholdD.StartAlder = mdtp.StartAlder
 AND ajourholdD.OpphorsAlder = mdtp.OpphorsAlder
 AND ajourholdD.PeriodeStartDatoAar = YEAR(mdtp.PeriodeStartDato)
 AND ajourholdD.PeriodeStartDatoManed = MONTH(mdtp.PeriodeStartDato)
 AND ajourholdD.maxAjourholdDato = mdtp.AjourholdDato
 WHERE mdtp.PeriodeStartDato <= @dato
 AND NOT EXISTS
 (
 SELECT * FROM
 dbo.cte_MDTForsikringssum dest
 WHERE dest.AvtaleNummer = mdtp.AvtaleNummer
 AND dest.MedlemskapNummer = mdtp.MedlemskapNummer
 AND dest.Dekningstype = mdtp.Dekningstype
 AND dest.StartAlder = mdtp.StartAlder
 AND dest.OpphorsAlder = mdtp.OpphorsAlder
 AND dest.GjelderFraDato = mdtp.PeriodeStartDato
 AND dest.EndretDato = mdtp.AjourholdDato
 )
OPTION(RECOMPILE);


DROP TABLE #TEMP;
```

**Closing note**

If there is more information, like the table definitions and some sample data, more can be done, these three rewrites simply look like the fastest and easiest wins at the time of writing.

Comment: Great answer! Amazing performance gain for solution 1 and 2 (I cannot test 3 in same environment with fresh data). I thought NOT EXISTS and LEFT JOIN behaved differently on handling NULL values, but it seems like I have been confused with NOT IN and NOT EXISTS. Can you confirm that results of LEFT JOIN and NOT EXISTS will be the same in all scenarioes?

Comment: @Creztian Great! The NULL values remark is true for the `NOT IN` but you do make a good point. If a different column than one of the join columns was used to check for the `IS NULL` the result could be different. Even if`AvtaleNummer` column has `NULL` values as data, then these are filtered out by the `LEFT JOIN` before applying the filter. As a result, In this case the `NOT EXISTS` does the same filtering but can apply it earlier in the execution plan. More information on this in this [excellent article](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) by Aaron Bertrand.

Comment: `UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION`, since `UNION` does an implicid `DISTINCT`, so you should prefer this (except you know that there are duplicates and want to get rid of them, but since there is already a `group by` in the sub statements, you would need to `GROUP` (and `SUM`) again in the outer query